# The well-known classifiers that can be trained/tested in linear time

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition

I am interested in collecting the list of the classifiers that (depending on their setting) **can have** linear time complexity (both in training and testing step) with respect to the number of samples $n$, the number of features of each sample $m$, and the number of classes $c$.

In other words, I am seeking for a list of the well-known classifiers that can have the complexity of **$\mathcal{O}(mnc)$** or lower.

1- I know that Naive Bayes classifiers are so; given that the parameters of the utilized probability distributions can be estimated in linear time (e.g. Poisson Naive Bayes and Multinomial Naive Bayes)

2- I also know that when K-NN is utilized as classifier (counting the K-nearest neighbors and choosing the most-voted class), it is also included in this list.

Although this list, in theory, can be extended infinitively, I am interested in completing the list by the well-known classifiers by the CS community.

I searched the web, a lot, but seemingly, there is no page even speaking about such subject or such list. The only thing that I found was a lot of info about "linear classifiers" whose scope is much more general than my question (even their list includes SVM and etc.).

Comment: Define 'trained in linear time'.

Comment: Linear in what parameter?

Comment: We discourage list questions.  There are many many classifiers, so asking for a complete list of all classifiers with this property seems like it is asking a bit much.  We seek questions that can be answered in a paragraph or a few paragraphs.  Why do you want such a list?  What will you do with it?  Perhaps you can think of a more focused question that will be a better fit for this site's format.

Comment: @D.W. Of course, a complete list is not expected by me. It was very strange for me that I could find no web articles or papers that review the "well-known" classifiers from the Big-O point of view. There are a lot of web articles and papers that have reviewed classifiers from different points of view. But, I am interested to know which classifiers "theoretically guarantee" very fast performance that is appropriate for being trained and tested in real-time. The accepted answer is not still this, but I am used to accepting the almost-good answers until they are the best existing one.

Comment: @orlp If the classifier performance is dependent to $\{x_1, x_2, ... , x_n\}$ variables, then the training and the testing complexity are less than $\mathcal{O} (x_1 x_2 ... x_n)$.

Comment: Almost anything "can have" linear special cases. They are normally the boring cases, of very little (if any) interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Time Complexity of Training and Testing

### Linear with respect to training samples ($n$) and samples features ($m$) and number of classes ($c$).

Letting the list provided in the [weblog of @Martin_Thoma](https://martin-thoma.com/comparing-classifiers/) as the basis, I exhaustively searched the web and reached the following list.

The following classifiers potentially have computational complexities less than or equal with $\mathcal{O}(mnc)$ complexity) in both of the training and testing phases.

- k-nearest neighbors (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219655/k-nn-computational-complexity),
- Naive Bayes is linear for those PDFs that can be estimated in linear time (e.g. Poisson and Multinomial PDFs).
- Approximate SVM (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96995/machine-learning-classifiers-big-o-or-complexity)
- Logistic Regression can be linear (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4278/computational-complexity-of-learning-classification-algorithms-fitting-the-p)
- AdaBoost and Gradient Boosting require at least a weak learner and are linear only if their weak learner is linear (f m n log(n)) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397485/what-is-the-o-runtime-complexity-of-adaboost)
- Neural Networks can be linear (https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5728/time-complexity-for-training-a-neural-network)

The following classifiers are nonlinear either in the training or in the testing phase:

- SVM requires polynomial training with respect to the number of samples (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585465/training-complexity-of-linear-svm)
- Decision tree and correspondingly Random forest are loglinear (m n log(n)) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212610/why-is-the-runtime-to-construct-a-decision-tree-mnlogn)
- Linear (and Quadratic) Discriminant Analysis (LDA and QDA) are polynomial (n m^2) (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211177/comparison-of-lda-vs-knn-time-complexity)
- Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM) is polynomial with respect to m (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.html)

Comment: As you have three variables you're interested in (n, m, c), you should not write "k-nearest neighbors is linear", but rather something like $\mathcal{O}(n+m+c)$

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read my blog post [Comparing Classifiers](https://martin-thoma.com/comparing-classifiers/), especially the [MNIST summary](https://martin-thoma.com/comparing-classifiers/#mnist-summary_1).

## Time Complexity of Training

### By Training Samples

Let $n$ be the number of training samples.

The following classifiers can perform at least on training / fitting step in $\mathcal{O}(n)$:

- Neural Networks: You can take a fixed batch size. Then increasing $n$ is simply having more mini-batches to train on.
- $k$-nearest-neighbors: All "training steps"

The following classifiers cannot perform at least one training / fitting step in $\mathcal{O}(n)$:

- ???

I am unsure about the following:

- SVMs
- Decision Trees: I'm relatively sure it is linear, but I would need to go through one of the training algorithms

### By classes

If $n$ is the number of classes, then the training of $k$-NN is in $\mathcal{O}(1)$. If you keep the number of samples and k constant, then it doesn't matter if you have 2 classes or $10^{100}$.

I'm unsure about:

- Neural Networks: The size of the last layer grows. My intuition is that this is in $\mathcal{O}(n)$, but I need to put more thought into it. I am, however, not sure if the Big-O Time Complexity makes a lot of sense for this classifier. If you look at the [tables in Appendix D](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf), you see that in real problems the FLOPs are dominant in the beginning. Given a problem, you usually you can't influence the number of classes. And the wall-clock time complexity of training for two classes is vastly different for different classifiers. So much, that up to a reasonable amount of classes you will likely not see the asymptotic behavior.
- Decision trees might even be in $\mathcal{O}(1)$. I have to give impurity measures a closer thought.

Comment: I guess you're thinking about batch training. But I'm talking about a single mini-batch training run. that single one is constant in time complexity. And then you can train n times which is linear in n.

Comment: Sure you can change what you're looking at. But if you change the architecture you're changing the model. I was clear that I'm only looking at the training samples / classes.

Comment: Somebody edited my answer, while it should be another answer. I don't want this to be lost: https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/85080a53f73661f971a7ef4dba48364b

Comment: It was my answer after setting the utilized list in your weblog as the basis and exhaustively searching the web for finding the complexities. I saw it more polite not to make it a separate one.

Now, that it is your suggestion, I submit it as a separate one.

Comment: Thank you, @hossayni :-) Giving credit in you answer is enough. It is better than adding it to my answer, as you get credit for what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for your comment as well as your suggested edit. In addition, wish I could give a "+1" to your answer but the system does not let it to the users with less than 15 reputation scores.